# How to rollback any transaction when doing test with phpUnit in symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, phpunit, symfony-2.1

I'm testing the controllers using the crawler, but when I'm posting a form that doesn't generate any errors, it save the form in the database.

How can I prevent him to do so without changing the controller, and without testing something else.

Is there best practice about this kinds of test ?
I tried the rollback, but in the ControllerTest there is no more active transactions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to write your own test client class extending Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Client.
It's because default client doesn't share connection object between requests (so you can't use transactions outside test client). If you extend test client you can handle transaction by your own.

In your client class you need make static connection object, and override method doRequest() to avoid creating new connection object every time but use our static one instead.

It's well described here:

http://alexandre-salome.fr/blog/Symfony2-Isolation-Of-Tests

When you have your own doRequest method all you need is handle transaction, so you wrap handle() method with begin and rollback. Your doRequest method could look sth like that:

```
protected function doRequest($request)
{
    // here you need create your static connection object if it's doesn't exist yet
    // and put it into service container as 'doctrine.dbal.default_connection'

    (...)
    self::$connection->beginTransaction();
    $response = $this->kernel->handle($request);
    self::$connection->rollback();
    (...)

    return $response
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read the documentation of PHPUnit for database testing

http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.6/en/database.html

You will need setup your database and teardown the changes you made.

If you think that the above is too complicated maybe you are interested in make a mockup of your database layer

http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.6/en/test-doubles.html

Mockup is create a custom object based in the original object where put your own test controls. Probably in this case you are interested in mockup the Entity Manager of Doctrine

Comment: documentation of PHPUnit for database testing is not helping and links you provided is not working.